# TMC2208 v1.2 stepper motor drivers not detected on SKR 1.4 turbo with RepRap firmware

Tags: reprap, bigtreetech, skr-v1.4, tmc2208, tmc2209

I've upgraded my board to SKR1.4 Turbo with RepRap firmware. Everything works, but motors move double the request. `M112` reports them as 'no-driver-detected'.

```
    M112
    === Diagnostics ===
    RepRapFirmware for LPC176x based Boards (biquskr_1.4) version 3.2.2_2 running on LPC176x at 120Mhz
    Used output buffers: 3 of 16 (16 max)
    === RTOS ===
    Static ram: 4956
    Dynamic Memory (RTOS Heap 5): 8232 free, 8192 never used
    Allocations: 188 Frees: 34
    Never used RAM 256, free system stack 18 words
    Tasks: NETWORK(ready,195) HEAT(blocked,243) MAIN(running,358) IDLE(ready,21)
    Owned mutexes: WiFi(NETWORK)
    === Platform ===
    Last reset 00:05:40 ago, cause: [software]
    Last software reset at 2021-07-06 23:53, reason: User, GCodes spinning, available RAM 80, slot 2
    Software reset code 0x0003 HFSR 0x00000000 CFSR 0x00000000 ICSR 0x00425000 BFAR 0xe000ed38 SP 0x00000000 Task MAIN Freestk 0 n/a
    Error status: 0x04
    Aux0 errors 0,0,0
    Supply voltage: under voltage events: 0
    Driver 0: position 37762, no-driver-detected
    Driver 1: position 37762, no-driver-detected
    Driver 2: position 37762, no-driver-detected
    Driver 3: position 0, no-driver-detected
    Driver 4: position 0
    Driver 5: position 0
    Driver 6: position 0
    Date/time: 2021-07-06 23:59:06
    Slowest loop: 9.08ms; fastest: 0.10ms
    Step timer: target 197699275 count 340845874 delta -143146599 late 0
    USBSerial connected 0
    ADC not ready 2 ADC error threshold 10 ADC Init 1
    Ints: 0; Calls 0; fast: 4294967295uS; slow 0uS adj 0 bad 0 big delta 0
    PWM Channels
    Delta -1660064855 Start -1 End -1
    === Storage ===
    Free file entries: 6
    SD card 0 detected
    SD card longest read time 1.5ms, write time 0.0ms, max retries 0
    === Move ===
    DMs created 40, maxWait 159279ms, bed compensation in use: none, comp offset 0.000
    === DDARing ===
    Scheduled moves 21, completed moves 21, hiccups 0, stepErrors 0, LaErrors 0, Underruns [0, 0, 12], CDDA state -1
    === Heat ===
    Bed heaters = 0, chamberHeaters = -1
    === GCodes ===
    Segments left: 0
    Movement lock held by null
    HTTP is idle in state(s) 0
    File is idle in state(s) 0
    USB is idle in state(s) 0
    Aux is idle in state(s) 0
    Trigger is idle in state(s) 0
    Queue is idle in state(s) 0
    Daemon is idle in state(s) 0
    Autopause is idle in state(s) 0
    Code queue is empty.
    === Network ===
    Slowest loop: 191.40ms; fastest: 0.00ms
    Responder states: HTTP(2) HTTP(0)
    HTTP sessions: 1 of 2
    - WiFi -
    Network state is active
    WiFi module is connected to access point 
    Failed messages: pending 0, notready 0, noresp 0
    WiFi firmware version 1.25-01LE-D
    WiFi MAC address 74:59:09:3b:82:bd
    WiFi Vcc 2.93, reset reason Turned on by main processor
    WiFi flash size 4194304, free heap 36360
    WiFi IP address 192.168.0.200
    WiFi signal strength -80dBm, mode 802.11n, reconnections 0, sleep mode modem
    Clock register 00181001
    Socket states: 0 0
```

But `M569` seems to be able to communicate with the drivers:

```
    M569 P0
    Drive 0 runs in reverse, active low enable, timing fast, mode stealthChop, ccr 0x00053, toff 3, tblank 0, tpwmthrs 2000 (4.7 mm/sec), pwmScaleSum 0, pwmScaleAuto 0, pwmOfsAuto 0, pwmGradAuto 0, pos 0

    M569 P0 D2

    M569 P0
    Drive 0 runs in reverse, active low enable, timing fast, mode spreadCycle, ccr 0x00053, toff 3, tblank 0, hstart/hend/hdec 5/0/0, pos 0
```

As you can see, I managed to change the setting from 'stealthChop' to 'spreadCycle'.

I also tried editing the `config.g` to check if the stepping is set correctly and, unfortunately, it is.

Both `M350 X16 Y16 Z16 E16 I1` and `M350 X256 Y256 Z256 E256` make the stepper motors run twice the distance in mm required.

I can fix this problem by setting the steps per mm from 80 to 40, but I always ran 80 and online calculators say that my steps/mm are 80.

Is there something that I missed checking? How is it possible that the motors spin twice the required?

Comment: Hi Chris and welcome to SE.3DP. +1 for an intriguing and well presented question. Hopefully someone may be able to answer your question in a few days. Good luck!